# what are the ways we can reduce the deadlock possibilities?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Our application is facing deadlock situations

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:308) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3069) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2948) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3328) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2270) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 52 more
```

We are using Spring JPA transactions for commit. The deadlock is not happening always. Its happenig when the so many requests are coming from web service request and when doing some other activities in GUI at the same time. So there is a possiblity of accessing the same tables getting used from GUI as well as from web service at the same time. 
Analysing log files, we are also not getting information on which table is getting locked. Any suggestions on this. Also please let us know what are the things we should consider to reduce the deadlock possiblities?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to use strict lock order, both for tables and within tables. I.e. if you are going to update tables A, B and C, lock A first then lock B then lock C and if you are going to update two records in A, lock the one with lowest primary key value first. I've seen applications designed that way, but it is very expensive and almost never done in practice. A more pragmatic approach is to use guards.

For example, assume that the user interface and the web services work with customers and orders. You could decide to make the customer entity into a guard. To update an order one would first have to lock the order's customer. Using the same guard for the customer's address, order lines and so on means there is only one entity that must be locked for several use cases.

The affected use cases would then first identify their guard (customer in this case) and get a pessimistic lock (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-locking002.htm) on it. Then they can proceed without further code changes. As everyone starts trying to get the same lock some transactions will have to wait, but there will be no deadlocks as they lock the guard in order.

Performance may be affected as this can reduce concurrency, but provided that you can identify a good guard it should get rid of the deadlocks.

Another option is to catch the error and retry the transaction if that is possible.

EDIT:

If you can trace you can get a deadlock graph from SQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/analyze-deadlocks-with-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017), but just looking at the code you should see what tables you are updating.

Comment: This is a Hibernate question.  How are you going to tell Hibernate the order to lock the tables?

Comment: According to the tag it is a JPA question (with Hibernate as provider) so the link I provided should work. Lock the entities manually with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in the proper order and with a guard only a single find is needed to lock it, the rest of the code is unchanged. One could also set hibernate.order_updates=true and get some help from the framework, but that affects ids not tables and probably won't help much.